# Combination - Probability. Probability within a set of 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I am stuck on a homework question. The question is

---

**If there are 6 couples. (12 individuals) and 6 prizes are to be given out to these 12 individuals. What is the probability of a couple receiving a price.**

---

I know that there are $^{12}C_6$ possible ways to give out a prize. So that is the total number of outcomes.

Whats confusing me is how should I find the probability of the set consisting of 2 people i.e a couple

any hints to help me out?

---

**Edit** any one can receiv a price, Even two people who are coupled

Comment: When is a considered that a couple received a prize ? Is it when both the individuals receive a prize or just one of them receiving a prize will do ?

Comment: The question is not stated clearly. It could ask for the probability that one *specific* couple either receives at least one, or exactly one prize (two possible interpretations), but as stated it would seem to be ask for the probability that *some* couple receives a prize. That would be 100%, unless one insists on _exactly one_ prize. Finally one could also pedantically defend the answer 0%, since prizes are given to individuals, never to couples. And then there is the possibility of considering the couple to receive a prize only if both of its members do (but it should then say "prizes").

Comment: thanks for your response lsp and marc, Any one can receive the prize, it can even be both people who are coupled. I hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We interpret the question as asking for the probability that there is **at least** one couple such that each member of the couple receives a prize.

We first find the probability of the complementary event, that there is **no** couple such that each member of the couple receives a prize.

Since conveniently there are $6$ prizes and $6$ couples, one member of each couple must receive a prize. Which member? There are $2^6$ choices.

So now we can find the probability that no two coupled people get a prize, and then the probability that there is at least one couple both of whose members get a prize.

Comment: thanks for your reply! I makes sense when you use the compliment and do 1-comp. Didn't think of it like that! Going to keep this in mind. thanks for the hint! or rather answer? which u edited out?

Comment: I thought hat having a comment and an answer was overkill. The answer became Community wiki for reasons mysterious to me. The other answer (particular couple) interprets the question in a different manner. As mentioned in comments, the question is somewhat imprecise.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking at a particular couple and you want the probability that at least one wins a prize, you could approach it by considering:

- What is the probability the first member of the couple wins a prize?
- If the first member of the couple does not win a prize, what is the conditional probability the second wins a prize? Multiply this by the probability the first member of the couple does not win a prize.
- Add the two previous results together

Another approach giving the same result:

- What is the probability the first member of the couple does **not** win a prize?
- If the first member of the couple does not win a prize, what is the conditional probability the second does **not** win a prize?
- Multiply these together to get the probability the couple does **not** win a prize.
- Find the probability the couple wins at least one prize

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting the question as asking for the probability, for one specific couple, of receiving at least one prize, one can argue as follows. There are $N=\binom{12}6$ ways to distribute the prizes, (supposedly) all equally likely. Among these there are $M=\binom{10}6$ ways for the prizes to be distributed only among the remaining couples (our couple loses). Then the probability asked for is $\frac{N-M}N$.